# Date query in flask-sqlalchemy empty when equal, non-empty when ge or le

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have sqlalchemy connecting to a sqllite database in a small flask app.

If I do:

```
check = MyTable.query.filter(MyTable.run_dt >= datetime.date(2017,12,14)).all()
```

Then I receive a sqlalchemy object that contains a list of all rows with run_dt greater than or equal to 2017-12-14. It contains several rows with a date '2017-12-14'. This is what I would expect.

If I do:

```
check = MyTable.query.filter(MyTable.run_dt == datetime.date(2017,12,14)).all()
```

I get an empty set. I can't figure out why.

run_dt is a db.Column(db.Date) in the model object. I've tried switching it to strings and it didn't work.

In fact, doing the above with strings works.

I'm sorry if this is a goofy question, but I find it bewildering and appreciate any help anyone can give.

Comment: If i do
    check = MyTable.query.filter(MyTable.run_dt >= '2017-12-14', MyTable.run_dt <= '2017-12-15').all()
I get only the 14th. I guess I can make this work, but it seems pretty dumb. Why doesn't equal work?

Comment: If I change run_dt to a db.Column(db.String) type and then filter on '2017-12-14 00:00:00' it works. I don't love this solution though; it suggests that when I define run_dt as a Date that I'm not using it correctly.

Comment: If you want people to be able answer, include the model and sample data in a question such as this ("Why am I not getting my data"). In other words a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one solution is to strftime the date into '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' format. This solves the problem.

However, I don't understand why this works and datetime.datetime(2017,12,14,0,0,0) does not work.